# Issue using image from an enum in react

Tags: reactjs

I've made an enum in a `conf.js` file to load images depending on the selected value.

```js
import Cra from './assets/dofus/cra.png'

const charac = {
    1: 'assets/feca.png',
    2: 'assets/osa.png',
    3: 'assets/enu.png',
    4: 'assets/sram.png',
    5: 'assets/xel.png',
    6: 'assets/ecaflip.png',
    7: 'assets/eni.png',
    8: 'assets/iop.png',
    9: {Cra},
    10: 'assets/sadi.png',
    11: 'assets/sacri.png',
    12: 'assets/panda.png',
    13: 'assets/roub.png',
    14: 'assets/zob.png',
    15: 'assets/steamer.png',
    16: 'assets/elio.png',
    17: 'assets/hupper.png',
    18: 'assets/ougi.png'
}

export default charac
```

But when I'm trying to display it in my function like this:

```js
<Image src={charac[character[selected - 1]._id]} alt={character[selected - 1].name} />
```

By printing the `charac[character[selected - 1]._id` it's showing the path of my img so this part works.

I have an error saying

> [object%20Object]:1 GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 500 (Internal Server Error)

But if I load the image in the same file as the `Image` balise, it works

```js
import Cra from '../assets/dofus/cra.png'
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image'

<Image src={Cra} alt={character[selected - 1].name} />
```

The character json looks like this, and so on untile the 18th value:

```json
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "ankamaId": 1,
        "name": "Feca",
        "level": null,
        "type": "classe",
        "url": "https://www.dofus.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/classes/1-feca",
        "description": "\nProtecteur\nLes Fécas sont de loyaux protecteurs toujours sur la défensive. Ils sont appréciés dans les groupes d'aventuriers pour leurs armures élémentaires et leur capacité à encaisser les coups durs.\n\nIls sont également maîtres dans l'art des signes magiques : quand il va y avoir du grabuge, les Fécas sortent leurs glyphes ! ",
        "roles": [
            "Protection",
            "Tank",
            "Entrave"
        ],
        "spells": [
            {
                "name": "Aveuglement ",
                "variant": "Éblouissement "
            },
            {
                "name": "Attaque Naturelle ",
                "variant": "Attraction Naturelle "
            },
            {
                "name": "Rempart ",
                "variant": "Fortification "
            },
            {
                "name": "Typhon ",
                "variant": "Bourrasque "
            },
            {
                "name": "Bulle ",
                "variant": "Boursoufflure "
            },
            {
                "name": "Barricade ",
                "variant": "Pavois "
            },
            {
                "name": "Glyphe Agressif ",
                "variant": "Glyphe Fulminant "
            },
            {
                "name": "Léthargie ",
                "variant": "Atonie "
            },
            {
                "name": "Attaque Nuageuse ",
                "variant": "Attaque Orageuse "
            },
            {
                "name": "Bastion ",
                "variant": "Manoeuvre "
            },
            {
                "name": "Retour du Bâton ",
                "variant": "Tétanie "
            },
            {
                "name": "Téléglyphe ",
                "variant": "Égide "
            },
            {
                "name": "Glyphe de Répulsion ",
                "variant": "Barrière "
            },
            {
                "name": "Trêve ",
                "variant": "Renfort "
            },
            {
                "name": "Glyphe d'Aveuglement ",
                "variant": "Glyphe Protecteur "
            },
            {
                "name": "Frisson ",
                "variant": "Tension "
            },
            {
                "name": "Glyphe Optique ",
                "variant": "Glyphe d'Itinérance "
            },
            {
                "name": "Torpeur ",
                "variant": "Flamme Latérale "
            },
            {
                "name": "Mise en Garde ",
                "variant": "Ataraxie "
            },
            {
                "name": "Glyphe gravitationnel ",
                "variant": "Glyphe d'Excursion "
            },
            {
                "name": "Glyphe Enflammé ",
                "variant": "Glyphe de Perception "
            },
            {
                "name": "Bouclier Féca ",
                "variant": "Inertie "
            }
        ],
        "maleImg": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/renderer/look/7b317c31302c323031327c313d31363736353536342c323d373039383135372c333d31353937323931322c343d353436383235342c353d373039383135377c3132357d/full/1/250_250-10_100.png",
        "femaleImg": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/renderer/look/7b317c31312c323032307c313d31363130333737352c323d363833333138342c333d31333636313139302c343d31333636313139302c353d363936333436327c3132357d/full/1/250_250-10_100.png"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "ankamaId": 2,
        "name": "Osamodas",
        "level": null,
        "type": "classe",
        "url": "https://www.dofus.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/classes/2-osamodas",
        "description": "\nInvocateur de créatures\nLes Osamodas sont des dompteurs nés ! Ils ont le pouvoir d'invoquer des créatures et sont de remarquables dresseurs. Une rumeur prétend qu'ils taillent leurs vêtements dans la peau de leurs ennemis, mais allez donc leur demander ce qu'il en est...\n\nSi vous êtes de son côté, un Osamodas sera aux petits soins pour vous. Dans le cas contraire, peut-être terminerez-vous votre vie sous la forme d'une botte ou d'un bonnet fourré. ",
        "roles": [
            "Invocation",
            "Soins",
            "Amélioration"
        ],
        "spells": [
            {
                "name": "Dragonique ",
                "variant": "Reptincelles "
            },
            {
                "name": "Geyser ",
                "variant": "Aquaculture "
            },
            {
                "name": "Prime ",
                "variant": "Favoritisme "
            },
            {
                "name": " Canine ",
                "variant": "Croc Répulsif "
            },
            {
                "name": "Fossile ",
                "variant": "Sédimentation "
            },
            {
                "name": "Baume Protecteur ",
                "variant": "Quart "
            },
            {
                "name": "Équilibre Bestial ",
                "variant": "Ponction "
            },
            {
                "name": "Onde Aquatique ",
                "variant": "Poison Cinglant "
            },
            {
                "name": "Corbeau Embrasé ",
                "variant": "Écaille Transversale "
            },
            {
                "name": "Second ",
                "variant": "Résistance naturelle "
            },
            {
                "name": "Plumeau ",
                "variant": "Déplumage "
            },
            {
                "name": "Frappe du craqueleur ",
                "variant": "Constriction "
            },
            {
                "name": "Rappel ",
                "variant": "Remplacement "
            },
            {
                "name": "Piqûre Motivante ",
                "variant": "Quint "
            },
            {
                "name": "Souffle du dragon ",
                "variant": "Cœur de Dragon "
            },
            {
                "name": "Pilon Laineux ",
                "variant": "Toison Bouffante "
            },
            {
                "name": "Envol ",
                "variant": "Gambade "
            },
            {
                "name": "Tierce ",
                "variant": "Relais "
            },
            {
                "name": "Tourbillon ",
                "variant": "Batra "
            },
            {
                "name": "Laisse Spirituelle ",
                "variant": "Feu sacrificiel "
            },
            {
                "name": "Fouet ",
                "variant": "Cravache "
            },
            {
                "name": "Bénédiction Animale ",
                "variant": "Sixte "
            }
        ],
        "maleImg": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/renderer/look/7b317c32302c323032387c313d31353937333437302c323d31363737373136362c333d343833363537332c343d323832373032372c353d31363736313930347c3133307d/full/1/250_250-10_100.png",
        "femaleImg": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/renderer/look/7b317c32312c323033367c313d31363735393337362c323d31363737373136342c333d323732363539342c343d323832373032372c353d323732363539347c3132357d/full/1/250_250-10_100.png"
    },
```

Comment: Can you sare how the `character` object looks?

Comment: can u try changing ```import Cra from '../assets/dofus/cra.png'``` to ```import cra from '../assets/dofus/cra.png'```

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the conf file.

I wrote

```js
const charac = {
    1: 'assets/feca.png',
    2: 'assets/osa.png',
    3: 'assets/enu.png',
    4: 'assets/sram.png',
    5: 'assets/xel.png',
    6: 'assets/ecaflip.png',
    7: 'assets/eni.png',
    8: 'assets/iop.png',
    9: {cra},
    10: 'assets/sadi.png',
    11: 'assets/sacri.png',
    12: 'assets/panda.png',
    13: 'assets/roub.png',
    14: 'assets/zob.png',
    15: 'assets/steamer.png',
    16: 'assets/elio.png',
    17: 'assets/hupper.png',
    18: 'assets/ougi.png'
}
```

instead of

```js
const charac = {
    1: 'assets/feca.png',
    2: 'assets/osa.png',
    3: 'assets/enu.png',
    4: 'assets/sram.png',
    5: 'assets/xel.png',
    6: 'assets/ecaflip.png',
    7: 'assets/eni.png',
    8: 'assets/iop.png',
    9: cra,
    10: 'assets/sadi.png',
    11: 'assets/sacri.png',
    12: 'assets/panda.png',
    13: 'assets/roub.png',
    14: 'assets/zob.png',
    15: 'assets/steamer.png',
    16: 'assets/elio.png',
    17: 'assets/hupper.png',
    18: 'assets/ougi.png'
}
```